# How to replace particular character in string with tcl script?

Tags: string, tcl, character-replacement

```
set some_string "Name/is/ComplexSTRUCTUre"
```

convert this string to,

```
some_string = "Name/is/ComplexSTR.CTUre"
```

i.e replacing first `"U"` to `"."`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try This,

```
set replaced_string [regsub "U" $some_string "."]
puts $replaced_string
```

Another Option,

```
set pos [string first "U" $some_string]
set replaced_string [string replace $some_string $pos $pos "."]
puts $replaced_string
```

Here your `"Name/is"` portion should not contain any `"U"`

More information can be found here [tcl string replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094697/tcl-string-replacement)

Answer (score 5):

Use of `regsub` is overkill for plain strings. If you simply wish to replace one set of substrings with another, `string map` is your friend:

```
set s "Name/is/ComplexSTRUCTUre"

set s [string map {U .} $s]
```

This, however, will replace *all* Us with dots -- as your question's *title* suggests.

If, however, you want only *the first* U replaced -- as the *text* of your question implies, then AxT_8041's second option is the most suitable.

Comment: `string map` don't allows user to change only first occurrence. it changes every occurrence of `U` with dot which is not OP's need. Still if you want change all occurrence thn `string map` is nice and sweet option

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
string replace <num1> <num2> <To_be_replaced>
```

**example:**

```
set a [get_attr [get_cells -filter <cell_name> ] ref_name]
<cell_name>

string replace 5 8 NAME
<cell_NAME>
```